# What does this git message, (Another git process seems to be running in this repository, e.g.) mean?

Tags: git

I am learning Git right now and have done a few things but I got this message. Can someone explain what it means please? [image: Git commit error]

I tried to create a new repository and save a project inside it.

Comment: Please paste text as a code block and not an image.  Images aren't searchable or accessible.

Comment: When you're asking for help, you’ll get more/better answers if you [don’t post screenshots or photos](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Cut & paste the text directly into the message.

Why?
1. It's easier for people to read it.
2. It allows those reading it to cut & paste the text, making it easier to work on solving your problem.
3. It makes it searchable, so that someone can find this thread when Googling for information in the future.
4. A screen reader can't read a picture which limits access to some in our community.

See also http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Answer (score 1):

In order to be safe in the face of concurrent processes, Git uses lock files and updates the file in question by writing the data to the lock file, then atomically replacing the original file with the lock file.

This messages means that the lock file in question already exists.  The message provided is typically preceded by a line that says something like "Unable to create index.lock" or such.  The file in question that's being modified is in that portion of the error message.  If the message says "index.lock", then that typically means that something is trying to modify the index, where the changes for the next commit are stored.

Sometimes this is your editor, and sometimes it's another process on the system.  We don't know for certain what it is without access to your system.

There are some things that can also cause this problem, though.  Sometimes on Windows an antivirus can cause the rename to fail, leaving the lock behind, and you can also get this problem if you're using a cloud syncing service like OneDrive or Dropbox to hold your repositories.  You should never store a repository in a folder managed by a cloud syncing service because that very frequently corrupts repositories, and you're strongly advised to use only Windows Defender (and not third-party antiviruses) on Windows.

If you're willing to lose whatever data is in progress, you can remove the lock file (which is often in the `.git` directory) and then proceed with your operation.  However, if it continues to occur, you'll need to figure out what's causing this problem and fix it.